# Clebsch-Gordan Identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I'm trying to take advantage of a particular identity for the sum of the product of three Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, however, the present form of my equation is slightly different.  Is there a symmetry relation that will allow me to change:

$\sum_{\alpha\beta\delta}C_{a\alpha b\beta}^{c\gamma}C_{d\delta b\beta}^{e\epsilon}C_{d\delta f\phi}^{a\alpha}$

Into:

$\sum_{\alpha\beta\delta}C_{a\alpha b\beta}^{c\gamma}C_{d\delta b\beta}^{e\epsilon}C_{a\alpha f\phi}^{d\delta}$

Notice I need to swap $j_2m_2$ with $jm$ in the last Clebsh-Gordan coefficient.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

Note: My notation follows that of Varshalovich, $C_{j_1 m_1 j_2 m_2}^{jm}$

Comment: What are those sums supposed to add up to?

Comment: What range are those sums over?

Comment: @Dan: The sums are over all valid values of the arguments, specifically $-a\leq\alpha\leq a, -b\leq\beta\leq b, -d\leq\delta\leq d$

Comment: In that case this equivalence is true only when $a=d$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $C^{22}_{1111}=1$ but $C^{11}_{2211}=0$. I don't think that this is true unless $a=d$ and the sums over $\alpha$ and $\delta$ have the same range.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot make the change you suggest because of the condition on projections.  In your first equation, the projections in your last CG must satisfy 
$\delta +\phi=\alpha$ 
whereas in your second equation, the projections in your last CG must satisfy
$\alpha+\delta=\phi$.
Thus, unless there is further symmetry that you have not mentioned in your problem, for instance $\alpha=\delta$, there is no way to transform the first into the second.